# How to do a binding from a column into another column using SFDataGrid filled by MappingName

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, syncfusion

I'm trying to condition the number of decimals in a column acording to the boolean value of another column in the same row.

this is the XAML

```
                    <syncf:GridCheckBoxColumn HeaderText="Headeer1"
                                              MappingName="OnlyIntegerQuantities"
                                              Width="120"
                                              AllowEditing="True"/>

                    <syncf:GridNumericColumn           HeaderText="Header2"
                                                       MappingName="Quantity"
                                                       Width="120"
                                                       AllowEditing="True"
                                                       Decimals="{Binding DataContext.OnlyIntegerQuantities,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=syncf:VirtualizingCellsControl}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToDecimalConverter}}"
                                                       ValidationMode="Decimal"/>
```

if i do the binding to any property in the ViewModel them works fine but i can't do the binding to the property in the model that fills the row.

i have tried binding to the relative source of the CellsControl but doesn't work.

i'm using an ObservableCollection to fill the ItemsSource of the datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GridTemplateColumn` instead of `GridNumericColumn` and define template with TextBlock inside. Set `Text` property using multibinding with a multi-value converter.

```xml
<syncf:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Header2" MappingName="Quantity" Width="120" AllowEditing="True">
    <syncf:GridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Text">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BooleanToDecimalConverter}">
                                    <Binding Path="Quantity"/>
                                    <Binding Path="OnlyIntegerQuantities"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </syncf:GridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</syncf:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Converter

```cs
public class BooleanToDecimalConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var quantity = (double)values[0];
        var onlyQuantityInteger = (bool)values[1];
        if (onlyQuantityInteger)
        {
            return String.Format("{0:0}", quantity);
        }
        else
        {
            return (quantity).ToString();
        }
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```